# Error While creating Store Procedures in Sql Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating store procedure in SQL server with C#.but getting error
that "Error Occurred while the batch was being executed".
Here is my Query

```
    CREATE Procedure [dbo].[SP_empInsert]

    @empCode VARCHAR(50),
    @empName VARCHAR(50),
    @empCellNum VARCHAR(50),
    @empAddress VARCHAR(50),
    @empdate VARCHAR(50)
AS
   INSERT INTO Employee values                  
      (@empCode,@empName,@empCellNum,@empAddress,@empdate)
return 0
```

**C#**

```
conn.Open(); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SP_empInsert", conn); 

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empCode",txtid )) //Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text) 

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empName", txtname.Text)); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empCellNum", txtquantity.Text)); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empAddress", txtprice.Text)); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empdate", dateTimePicker1.Text)); 

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the C# code?

Comment: The error is not with what you have pasted, you need to add more details including the code that invokes the SP

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empCode",txtid ));//Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empName", txtname.Text));

Comment: Are you getting error while SP creation or while calling this into your C# code?

Comment: Error occurred while Creation

Comment: you should specify the error in order to help you?? what is the exception message ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Create and run your stored procedure including the field names against your database for example:

```
   USE Sample
       CREATE Procedure [dbo].[SP_empInsert]
  (@empCode VARCHAR(50),
    @empName VARCHAR(50),
    @empCellNum VARCHAR(50),
    @empAddress VARCHAR(50),
    @empdate VARCHAR(50))
    AS
       INSERT INTO Employee (EmpCode, EmpName, EmpCellNum, EmpAddress, EmpDate) 
           VALUES (@empCode,@empName,@empCellNum,@empAddress,@empdate)
```

Make sure the Stored Procedure is created in the Database in SQLServer:

[image]

Comment: Here is my actual error Creating [dbo].[SP_empInsert]...
(67,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_empInsert, Line 10 Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: make sure that the columns match what is in the SQL script.

Comment: my Store Procedure is created a bit ago and showing in directory but a new exception come when I runs the program

Comment: System.Argument Exception:No Mapping Exists from Object type

Comment: Can you update your question by showing the table definition?

Comment: Thanks @Oluwafemi my problem solve now.thanks again for your help.

Comment: last thing plz from where I can see the values  inserted in storeprocedure

Comment: through query?or from directory?

Comment: You can see values in debug mode of C# runtime before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score -1):

The error is not in the SP syntax. There might be some resource issue at your end. Please refer this link for more details: [SQL Server - An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: The directory name is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704914/sql-server-an-error-occurred-while-executing-batch-error-message-is-the-dire)

Comment: How is this an answer?