# SQL Server 2008: Error creating window handle

Tags: sql-server, window-handles

I have `N` number of tables in my database, which holds around 0.6 million records. I've created a SQL script which copies this data into same tables (basically it's a script to generate more data). I've tested the script it runs fine for small data (10k records). When I tried it to copy all data, it throws an error:

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Error creating window handle.

1.What is the meaning of this error in SQL Server?

2.Does it has to do anything with my SQL in script, or is this cause of other component of SQL Server?

Comment: This is a `client side issue`. Reboot the client and check

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl I thought that solution is for win forms? Is it the same for SQL server?

Comment: yes it is. Check https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aeae8dc8-f45f-44df-881b-fa9d57948bde/an-error-occurred-while-executing-batch-error-message-is-error-creating-window-handle-sql-server?forum=transactsql

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl I check that, is it mentioned somewhere that it solved the problem? I think it was just a proposed solution.

Comment: You can check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704914/sql-server-an-error-occurred-while-executing-batch-error-message-is-the-dire

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl that is some other error.

Comment: You get the problem while running the script via Management Studio or via a custom application? Because as @MusicLovingIndianGirl says it's a client side issue. It's not SQL Server that throws the error. It's the application you use to run the query that throws it.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I'm running the script from Management Studio.

Comment: Then the error is thrown from Management Studio - not SQL Server. That's what is meant with "client side" issue. Have you tried rebooting? Also check your event viewer for error message that could indicate what the issue is.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I know now that it's the Management Studio error. I've rebooted but same problem is thrown again.

Comment: Check your event viewer for error message

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen it was query output that was causing the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handles are Windows tools to manage OS resources. When some app on your machine have memory leaks - you can run out of handles and this error occurs. Current state of handles can be seen in Task Manager (Handle Count)

As said in comments - it's a client side issue. For example large resultsets/query output to grid may end up to this error.

Solution: Reboot your PC, minimize the output of query. Also you can try to launch script via SQLCMD.

You can read more about it [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/27248/what-is-a-process-handle).

Some explanation [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic404984-149-1.aspx).

Comment: In my case it is the outputs of query that are causing the error.. thanks